# Jquery UI interface looks ugly before document.ready

Tags: jquery, user-interface, onload, document-ready

HTML elements show earlier then onload or document.ready is fired.

All jQuery UI widgets load on document.ready and it makes page look ugly for few first seconds.

Possible option to deal with it - hide elements before they are pimped out with jQuery UI and show them with JS after load. But in case JS is turned off - user will not see any elements neither standard HTML nor jQuery UI.

What is the best practice to work with it?

Comment: Newsflash: jQuery UI *always* looks ugly.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing... :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you look at the jQuery UI documentation, [let's take tabs for example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), if you look at the **Theming** tab, you can see the classes to apply to avoid the flash of unstyled content:

```
<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
   <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
   <div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab one content goes here.</p>
   </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Note: This *isn't* the best practice, but if you want to avoid showing the content, it's an option, here's another:

You can hide the elements via CSS, give those wrapping `<div>` elements a class, let's say `.startsUgly` which in your stylesheet has:

```
.startsUgly { display: none; }
```

....and show them in JavaScript, e.g. `$(".startsUgly").show();`

Then to handle those JavaScript disabled users, some `<noscript>` magic:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">.startsUgly { display: block; }</style>
</noscript>
```

this way, those with JavaScript disabled simple don't get the `display: none` effect, they'll still see the content.

Comment: Lets take for example buttons. We have HTML button in source: <button>bla-bla</button>. After jQuery UI loads is applys theming and settings: adds icon, remove caption etc. If you suggest style HTML button with CSS before load and make it look the same - what is the potin to use jQuery UI in this case at all?

Comment: @Alex - You'd have to apply all the child elements as well in your generated markup, so it's not an idea option...I added another above though, which still takes care of those with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: FWIW using the startsUgly solution for me ended up dumping content from all the tabs onto the page at once when calling $(".startsUgly").show().  I had more luck with the second solution by wrapping the startsUgly class in a visibility tag:

    .startsUgly {visibility:hidden;}

and then removing the classes on ready:

    $(".startsUgly").removeClass("startsUgly");

Not impossible that I was doing something wrong though...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the jQuery UI classes in the documentation only apply after document.ready. You can style them all you like, but you will not get rid of the flash of unstyled content. The classes are useful for theming the UI, not for affecting how things look before the UI is in place.

Second, the noscript tag is basically to be avoided, for a wealth of reasons:
1) It doesn't really tell you if javascript is on or not. For example, it could be enabled in the browser but blocked by a firewall.
2) It's a block level tag, so there are only certain places where it can validly appear. It's not an all-purpose solution.
3) The tag doesn't differentiate between degrees of javascript implementation on different systems.

You were closer to the best practice in your original post. The trick is to do both the hiding and the showing in javascript. First, style your page so that it will look acceptable with javascript disabled. Then, to prevent the flash of unstyled content, do the hiding of the ugly elements in javascript *before* document.ready (this is the critical part) by assigning a class to the html element:

```
jQuery('html').addClass('blahblah');
```

Because the html element exists already, it's valid to work with it before document.ready.
Then, like Nick says, put the offending elements in a div with the class "startsugly" and then put a line in your css that hides the offending elements:

```
.blahblah .startsugly {display: none;}
```

The point here is that the display:none only comes into play when javascript is enabled. Users with it disabled will still be able to access your content. Then, after document.ready, put in your jQuery UI "pimping" functions, and show the offending element again:

```
$(".startsUgly").show();
```

although if it's content that's only conditionally visible in an accordion or a tab structure, this last step might even be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Nick Craver's second suggestion - I have no intention of stealing his answer, just adding another option - you can leverage the beauty of Modernizr. Modernizr will add a simple `js` class to the html element if JavaScript is enabled. So what you can do is add a simple style to your main style sheet like the following which will only hide the body if JavaScript is enabled (since we have to use JavaScript later on to show the body):

```
main.js body
{
    display: block;
}
```

And then have a simple line of JavaScript like the following in your 'master page':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $("body").css("display", "block");
    }
</script>
```

It's a good solution if you are already using Modernizr for other things. Otherwise, if you have no other use for Modernizr, I would go with Nick Craver's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class*=" ui-"]').remove();
```